# Insert Images from folder and subfolder php

Tags: php, wamp, server

Im trying to insert into html all images that are on the folder "assets/imagens/" and on any subfolders. I also need help to validate not to echo the subfolders.

Im using the code below:

```
                  $path = "assets/imagens/"; 
                  $diretorio = dir($path); 
                  while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){ 
                    if($arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..'){
                      echo '<div href="#" class="list-group-item">';
                        echo '<span class="close-button" secao="imagens">x</span>';
                        echo "<img class='max-width' src='".base_url().$path.$arquivo."' />"; 
                      echo '</div>';
                    }
                  } 
                  $diretorio -> close();
```

Comment: Curious - what exactly is the current issue you'er experiencing ?

Comment: You need to check if the current $arquivo is folder or file, if folder you need to recursively do same process for that subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                      $path = "assets/imagens/"; 
                      echo_directory_images($path);

 function echo_directory_images($path)
{
                  $diretorio = dir($path); 
                  while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){ 
                    if($arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..'){
                       if( is_dir($path.$arquivo))
                       {
                          //if subfolder
                          echo_directory_images($path.$arquivo.'/')
                       }
                       else{
                      echo '<div href="#" class="list-group-item">';
                        echo '<span class="close-button" secao="imagens">x</span>';
                        echo "<img class='max-width' src='".base_url().$path.$arquivo."' />"; 
                      echo '</div>';
                       }
                    }
                  } 
}
```

You may want to give a try to this function. I doubt if this will work exactly but this will surely give an idea about how to recursively call folders and subfolders.

Comment: @Artur you may want to give it up Vote, If its solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function listDir( $path ) {
      global $startDir;
      $handle = opendir( $path );
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if( substr( $file, 0, 1 ) != '.' ) {
          if( is_dir( $path.'/'.$file ) ) {
            listDir( $path.'/'.$file );
          }
          else {
            if( @getimagesize( $path.'/'.$file ) ) {

              /*
              // Uncomment if using with the below "pic.php" script to
              // encode the filename and protect from direct linking. 
              $url = 'http://domain.tld/images/pic.php?pic='
                     .urlencode( str_rot13( substr( $path, strlen( $startDir )+1 ).'/'.$file ) );
              */

              $url='http://localhost/'.$path.'/'.$file; 
              substr( $path, strlen( $startDir )+1 ).'/'.$file;

              // You can customize the output to use img tag instead.
              echo "<a href='".$url."'>".$url."</a><br>";
               echo "<img class='max-width' src='".$url."' />";
            }
          }
        }
      }
      closedir( $handle );
} // End listDir function

$startDir = "assets/imagens/";
listDir( $startDir );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

For example:

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('assets/imagens');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
foreach ($entities as $name => $entity) {
    if ($entity->isDir()) {
        continue;
    }

    $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'gif') {
        echo '<img src="' . $entity->getPathname() . '" />';
    }
}
```